# BiQuadFilters vs MyOwnFilter - Javascript WebAudio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am doing downsampling 48hkz to 16khz. To do that, I need a filter to prevent aliasing. 
WebAudio API already has [filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode), and this is what I am looking for:

```
biquadFilter = context.createBiquadFilter();
biquadFilter.type = "lowpass";
biquadFilter.frequency.value = 12000;
biquadFilter.Q.value = 3;
```

But I can make this to with this simple algorithm:

```
//Order 3 - Indirect form 2
var a_coef = [1.000000000000000,  -0.965779713179161,   0.582644165984302 , -0.106017056545330];
var b_coef = [0.063855924532476,   0.191567773597429,   0.191567773597429,   0.063855924532476];

var z1 = 0; var z2 = 0; var z3 = 0; var z0 = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
  z0 = buffer[i] + a_coef[1] * z1-a_coef[2] * z2-a_coef[3] * z3;
  buffer[i] = b_coef[0] * z0 + b_coef[1] * z1+b_coef[2] * z2 + b_coef[3] * z3;
  z3 = z2; z2 = z1; z1 = z0;
};
```

Which way consumes more resources? BiquadFilters were writhed in native code? Is the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BiquadFilters are indeed written in native code and you're probably better of using those in 99.9% of the possible cases.

JavaScript engines can do some amazing optimisations that can put JS in the ballpark with native implementations, but probably not in this case. You really need to know how to "provide" the engines with optimizable code to get the kinds of boosts you'd need, which is a whole science in itself (one good starting point would be to never declare a var inside the loop).

Comment: So despite of the simplicity of the operations of "myownfilter". The filters of WebAudioAPI will always doing better job in the relation "results vs resources consumption".

Comment: Can you please give me the links where I can attest what parts of WAAPI was writed in native code?  @OskarEriksson

Comment: Sure thing! The BiquadNode  (and the rest of the API) can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/webaudio/BiquadFilterNode.cpp&sq=package:chromium